# How to Create New Array with Most Recent Timestamps from a Log Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If given an array of indices `let indices = [0,1,15,16,22]`.

And an array of objects

```
let history = [{
  id: 0
  status: 200,
  time: 123454678
}, {
  id: 1
  status: 404,
  time: 123454678
}, {
  id: 1
  status: 200,
  time: 123454678
}, {
  id: 1
  status: 404,
  time: 143454678
}, {
  id: 2
  status: 200,
  time: 103454678
}, etc.]
```

How could I create a new array that contains:

1. The status is 200
2. The most recent object at index (by timestamp)
3. Only one index per id

I think the pattern is something like the following, but I am not sure how to ensure that only one (most recent by id) object is pushed to `dataToUpdate`.

```
let dataToUpdate = [];
history.map((el, i) => {
  if (el.id.includes(indices) && el.status === 200 && some_other_check_for_id) {
    dataToUpdate.push(el);
  }
});
```

Comment: `dataToUpdate` should be `[]` and you can also do `dataToUpdate = [...dataToUpdate, el]`, but I think your code should work if I get it right

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the `history` by `timestamp`, then `filter` elements by `status` and `id` and remove duplicates after that using another `filter`:

```js
let indices = [0,1,15,16,22];

let history = [{
  id: 0,
  status: 200,
  time: 123454678
}, {
  id: 1,
  status: 404,
  time: 123454678
}, {
  id: 1,
  status: 200,
  time: 123454678
}, {
  id: 1,
  status: 404,
  time: 143454678
}, {
  id: 2,
  status: 200,
  time: 103454678
}]

const dataToUpdate = history
  .filter(el => el.status === 200 && indices.includes(el.id))
  .sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time)
  .filter((el, i, arr) => i === arr.findIndex((item) => item.id === el.id))

console.log(dataToUpdate)
```

Comment: Hm... I'm not seeing how the second filter ensures that the most recent object isn't removed. Is it because the array is already sorted?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, exactly, that's the idea

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: this returns a different ordered result set and is much slower, because of the second pass. the first filtring should be first. if so, it has less bad time/space complexity than a single loop approach for the data and the finding in the result set.

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, thank you for taking your time to review my answer. I have updated it according to your kind suggestion (I hope you don't mind).
Yes, your solution is more performance efficient so should there be large datasets I would go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by looking for `status` and `indices`. If valid, seach for an inserted object in the result set and either update or push the object to the result set.

```js
var indices = [0, 1, 15, 16, 22],
    values = [{ id: 0, status: 200, time: 123454678 }, { id: 1, status: 404, time: 123454678 }, { id: 1, status: 200, time: 123454678 }, { id: 1, status: 404, time: 143454678 }, { id: 2, status: 200, time: 103454678 }],
    result = values.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.status !== 200 || !indices.includes(o.id)) return r;
        var index = r.findIndex(({ id }) => id === o.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
            if (r[index].time < o.time) r[index] = o;
        } else {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly filter your array, to have in it only items, that is included in the indices array and their status is 200. Then filtered array convents into the map. That map contains most recent items belong to provided indices. Then it should be converted back to the array.

```js
let indices = [0,1,15,16,22];
let history = [
{
    id: 0,
    status: 200,
    time: 123454678
},
{
    id: 1,
    status: 404,
    time: 123454678
},
{
    id: 1,
    status: 200,
    time: 123454678
},
{
    id: 1,
    status: 200,
    time: 143454679
},
{
    id: 2,
    status: 200,
    time: 103454678
}];

const dataToUpdate = getMostRecentById(indices, history);

function getMostRecentById(ids, logs) {
    const recentsMap = logs.filter(log => {
            return ids.includes(log.id) && log.status === 200;
        })
        .reduce(getMostRecentMap, []);

  return Object.values(recentsMap);
}

function getMostRecentMap(mostRecentMap, currentLog) {
    const isAlreadyMappedByCurrentLogId = Boolean(mostRecentMap[currentLog.id]);
  
    if (!isAlreadyMappedByCurrentLogId) {
        mostRecentMap[currentLog.id] = { ...currentLog }; 
      
        return mostRecentMap;
    }
     
    const isIdsEqual = mostRecentMap[currentLog.id].id === currentLog.id;
    const isCurrentLogGoneLater = mostRecentMap[currentLog.id].time < currentLog.time;
  
    if (isIdsEqual && isCurrentLogGoneLater) {
        mostRecentMap[currentLog.id] = { ...currentLog };
    }
  
    return mostRecentMap;
}

console.log(dataToUpdate);
```